# What's the best way to export UTF8 data into Excel?

Tags: xml, excel, csv, utf-8, utf-16

So we have this web app where we support UTF8 data. Hooray UTF8. And we can export the user-supplied data into CSV no problem - it's still in UTF8 at that point. The problem is when you open a typical UTF8 CSV up in Excel, it reads it as ANSII encoded text, and accordingly tries to read two-byte chars like ø and ü as two separate characters and you end up with fail.

So I've done a bit of digging (the Intervals folks have a interesting post [about it here](http://www.myintervals.com/forum/discussion/280/making-csv-data-exports-with-utf8-more-excel-friendly/)), and there are some limited if ridiculously annoying options out there. Among them:

- supplying a UTF-16 Little Endian TSV file which Excel will interpret correctly, but which won't support multi-line data
- supplying the data in an HTML table with an Excel mime-type or file extension (not sure if this option supports UTF8)
- there are some three or four ways to get XML data into the various recent versions of excel, and those would support UTF8, in theory. SpreadsheetML, using custom XSLT, or generating the new Excel XML format via templating.

It looks like no matter what, I'm probably going to want to continue offering a plain-old CSV file for the folks who aren't using it for Excel anyway, and a separate download option for Excel.

What's the simplest way of generating that Just-For-Excel file that will correctly support UTF8, my dear Stack Overflowers? If that simplest option only supports the latest version of Excel, that's still of interest.

I'm doing this on a Rails stack, but curious how the .Net-ers and folks on any frameworks handle this. I work in a few different environments myself and this is definitely an issue that will becoming up again.

*Update 2010-10-22:* We had been using the Ruport gem in our time-tracking system [Tempo](http://keeptempo.com) to provide the CSV exports when I first posted this question. One of my coworkers, Erik Hollensbee, threw together a quick filter for Ruport to provide us with actual Excel XSL output, and I figured I'd share that here for any other ruby-ists:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruport'
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'stringio'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = "UTF-8"

include Ruport::Data

class Ruport::Formatter::Excel < Ruport::Formatter
  renders :excel, :for => Ruport::Controller::Table

  def output
    retval = StringIO.new

    if options.workbook
      book = options.workbook
    else
      book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    end

    if options.worksheet_name
      book_args = { :name => options.worksheet_name }
    else
      book_args = { }
    end

    sheet = book.create_worksheet(book_args)

    offset = 0

    if options.show_table_headers
      sheet.row(0).default_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new(
        options.format_options || 
        { 
          :color => :blue,
          :weight => :bold,
          :size => 18
        }
      )
      sheet.row(0).replace data.column_names
      offset = 1
    end

    data.data.each_with_index do |row, i|
      sheet.row(i+offset).replace row.attributes.map { |x| row.data[x] }
    end

    book.write retval
    retval.seek(0)
    return retval.read
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're forgetting creating an OleDB datasource and Excel Interop, but there are issues with those as well.

I recommend the [SpreadsheetML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226687.aspx) option.  It works pretty well, odds are your platform has some decent tools for building xml files, and it's fully supported as far back as OfficeXP.  Office2000 is not supported, but personal experience is that it works in a limited way.

Comment: "You're forgetting ... an OleDB..." 

Ssh! This is a unix environment, so I'd like to avoid that kind of Voodoo. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Richard - because of the 2nd paragraph, which does not rely on oledb. Though from the update that was posted more than 1 1/2 years later, there should be an answer here pointing people to Ruby Rupert.

Answer (score 9):

I found that if you set the charset encoding of the web page to utf-8, and then Response.BinaryWrite the UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF) at the top of the csv file, then Excel 2007 (not sure about other versions) will recognize it as utf-8 and open it correctly.

Comment: I've posted some code that does this here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9907364/150342

Comment: A discussion of how to do this is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389005/how-to-add-a-utf-8-bom-in-java

Answer (score 7):

After struggling with the same problem for a few hours I found this excellent post on the subject

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/09/exporting-data-to-csv-and-excel-in-your-rails-app/
quote :

> So, these are the three rules for
>   dealing with Excel-friendly-CSV:
>
> 1. Use tabulations, not commas.
> 2. Fields must NOT contain newlines.
> 3. Use UTF-16 Little Endian to send the file to the user. And include a
>      Little Endian BOM manually.

However, if you're using ruby, you problem is solved:
first you have the [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) gem

but i ended up using the spreadsheet gem which directly generates excell spreadsheets
(i have link limitation, just google spreadsheet + rubyforge)
Brilliant !

Answer (score 1):

If you create an XML with utf encoding and save it as a .xls it will open even those two-byte chars:

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

Comment: I did try just saving an XML document of tabular data with the extension .xls and then opened it with Excel for Mac 2003 and it just barfed on it. And a fair number of our users are Mac people.

Comment: I've never tried that with MAC but it supposed to work, XML is an standar

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue of sending UTF8 data to Excel. My solution:

The current version of the Perl Spreadsheet::WriteExcel cpan code correctly writes Excel files using UTF8 data.

So I wrote a Rails plugin that
a) opens a two-way pipe to a perl program
b) sends the data, a row at a time, to the perl program. I use Yaml as the message data format. (Standard Ruby yaml is not UTF8, there's a special version available, ya2yaml)
c) The perl program creates the excel file
d) When the Rails program indicates (via a yaml message) that the last row has been sent, the perl program creates the excel file and sends the status back to the rails program.

Of course, adding a perl program to a rails project via a parallel process and a pipe is very much in the "Engineering" spectrum rather than "Computer Science." (It gets the job done but is not elegant.) But it does work well and saved me the weeks it would take to port the WriteExcel code to Ruby. Also note that the currently available Ruby port of WriteExcel does not handle utf8.

My sw is permissive open source but I haven't gotten around to releasing it yet. If you want it in its current state, see http://sandbox.kluger.com/write_excel_v.5.tar

Note that you'll want to create your excel files in a background process, not in the process of the Rails controller since that would block other browser clients as you grind away producing the excel file. I use DelayedJob plugin, works well.

Hope this helps,

Larry

Answer (score 1):

I fell on this post looking for the Ruby answer to why Excel wouldn't properly load a CSV with utf-8 characters.  After searching around and experimenting this solution worked for me:

```
csv_content = CSV.generate(col_sep: "\t", headers: :first_row, encoding: 'utf-8') do |csv|
  csv << ["header1", "header2"]
  csv << ["content1", "content2"]
end
write_content = Iconv.conv("utf-16le", "utf-8", "\xEF\xBB\xBF")
write_content += Iconv.conv("utf-16le", "utf-8", csv_content)
File.open("listing.csv", 'wb') {|f| f.write(write_content) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Excel does not handle UTF-8 properly. 
You should use instead a code page that satisfy your needs

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
// codepage: 28591, codepage name:iso-8859-1, codepage display name: Western European (ISO)
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, as long as you add a UTF8 signature/BOM (EF BB BF).

Answer (score -3):

Try OpenOffice Calc - it's much more Unicode friendly - both Importing and Exporting CSV files with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The question was about how to export this data from a webapp in such a way that users can open it in Excel. It's probably not going to work to just tell all your clients to use openoffice.

Comment: To be fair, the poster is correct that OpenOffice is more unicode friendly than Excel.  I came here looking for a way to do this using Excel because I don't want to use OpenOffice anymore.