# Reading and writing Excel files using Ruby on a server without Excel installed

Tags: ruby, excel

I need to read and write (-> transform) Excel files on a Linux server, which of course does not have Excel installed. For Python there exists http://www.python-excel.org/. Is there something similar for Ruby? Processing of the latest Office format is probably not required. Just old xls files should be enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Parse Excel 95-2003 files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579635/ruby-parse-excel-95-2003-files)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with Gonzih, and I use roo fairly regularly. It allows me to read, write, and write using a template file.
The project is fairly well documented on their [site](http://roo.rubyforge.org/).

I always use something like:

```
input = Excel.new(path)
output = Array.new
input.default_sheet = input.sheets[sheet]
start.upto(input.last_row) do |row|
  output << input.row(row)
end

p output
=> a nested array representing the spreadsheat.

p output[0]
=> [row1_column_a, row1_column_b...]
```

to read a spreadsheet. note that the roo gem requires you to use `Excelx.new` instead of `Excel.new` if your file is a .xlsx.

to write you can:

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
write_sheet = book.create_worksheet
row_num = 0
input.each do |row|
  write_sheet.row(row_num).replace row
  row_num +=1
end
book.write "/path/to/save/to.xls"
```

where input is an array structured just like output was

Comment: @Some_other_guy he said "use the roo gem"

Comment: -rf: but but...I thought it can't write to excel!

Comment: Roo implements read access for all spreadsheet types and read/write access for Google spreadsheets. It can handle * OpenOffice * Excel * Google spreadsheets * Excelx * LibreOffice * CSV

Comment: @Some_other_guy Maybe it's changed in versions? My example code worked when I wrote it, but that was three years ago. is it not working now?