# How to HTML encode a csv export

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, csv

I get

```
 QuattrodeÂ®
```

From a string that is HTML encoded as

```
Quattrode®
```

when viewing inside Excel 2007.

**Routine**

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.ContentType = "text/comma-separated-values";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"Expired.csv\"");

        Response.RedirectLocation = "export.csv";

        Response.Charset = "";
        //Response.Charset = "UTF-8";//this does not work either.
        EnableViewState = false;

        ExportUtility util = new ExportUtility();

        Response.Write(util.DataGridToCSV(gridViewExport, ","));
```

Basically `DataGridToCSV()` uses  `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(stringBuilder.ToString());` and I can use visual studio's text visualizer and see the string looks correct (Quattrode®).

So something in the `Response` procedure or in Excel's interpretation of the file is not correct. Any idea how to fix?

---

**UPDATE**
Turns out that this is not interpreted properly in Excel or WordPad.  I open it up in Notepad and the symbol shows up properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to select the proper text encoding to use when importing CSV's into Excel, don't you? Make sure you're hitting the UTF-8 charset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also try this

```
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF32;
```

Comment: +1 Management just had a change of direction.  I'll have to try these later as I've backed out to an older version of the program.

Comment: Edited answer to use Encoding.UTF32 rather than UTF8.  This did fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3300854/150342
and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6460488/150342
Then put together this code:

```
    public static void WriteCSVToResponse(string csv, string filename)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] BOM = new byte[] { 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf };
        response.BinaryWrite(BOM);//write the BOM first
        response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv));
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Response.Charset = "";

Try using something like UTF-8

Comment: Good suggestion, but it didnt work.  I put `Response.Charset = "UTF-8";` and the issue is the same.

Comment: Try ISO-8859-13 as suggested by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525304(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: adding `Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-13";` produces the same result.

Comment: Try ´Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;´